# check if EPS/PDF file contains vector graphic

Tags: linux, debian, pdf, eps

I need to convert PDF files to EPS.. Then I need to strip all text and images.. So far this works

```
pdftocairo -f 1 -l 1 -eps test.pdf - | sed '/BT/,/ET/ d' | sed '/^8 dict dup begin$/,/^Q$/ c Q' > no_text_and_images.eps
```

But how to check if the EPS file even contains vector? I need to do some OCR on the output - but only if vector is present in the file.. If it only contains text and images I don't want to use resources to run it through a OCR process

Sample file: http://docdro.id/yJZTGBt

Comment: I have an idea, but I'd have to test it. Do you have a sample of a document that contains pages that contain the various permutations of {has,does not have} {vector,text,image}?

Comment: By the way, you may want to change the title from EPS to PDF since that's what you actually want. (And the solution may be easier from a PDF since there are more tools).

Comment: @hackerb9, sorry didn't see your comments.. have added a link to a sample pdf file :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use ImageMagick. The '-trim' option crops an image as small as possible and will tell you if your image is completely empty:

```
$ convert -trim no_text_images.eps foo.jpg
convert-im6.q16: geometry does not contain image [...]
```

Because the `convert` command does not return an error code for this warning, your shell script will need to grep the stderr.

```
if ! convert -trim no_text_images.eps foo.png 2>&1 |
     grep 'does not contain image'; then
    [ there's an image, so process it ]
else
    [ there's no image ]
fi
```

---

However, now that I see what you're working on I may have a simpler solution for you. Why not try using `ocrmypdf`? Just `sudo apt install ocrmypdf` to install it on your Debian box.

I ran it on the PDF you gave me and, even though I have my `tesseract` set to English, it got a reasonable rendering of the vector you have at the top of the form:

```
$ ocrmypdf  --force-ocr  --oversample 150  084.pdf  foo.pdf
$ pdftotext foo.pdf -  |  less
Sigurd
Otto M¢nsteds

Va]

Muller Vinhandel

A/S

Aalbors SV- Tlf. 98 18 50 99- E-mail: vin@smv.dk- www. smv. dk
53 92 79 12- Nordjyske Bank 7450- 2038354

2- 9200

CVR

nr.

Import, salg as distribution if Vin cg spiritus
Eneiurhandler i Danmark af

udsIgte vine fra hale verden.
```